# How do chain a null check in string.Select in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanted to join object values as a comma separated string which I have done using Join, but this does not null check for each object. If I have to add a null/undefined check, how do I chain it to join? What will be the best way to do it?

```
  class User{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public string Description {get;set}
}

public async Task<List<string>> getUser(List<User> users)
{
 var ids = string.Join(“,”, users.Select(user=>user.Id));
 var descriptions = string.Join(“,”, users.Select(user=>user.Description));
 return new List<string> {ids,descriptions};
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to nullecheck? The User object, or the properties?

Comment: The properties- Id and Description

Comment: So do you want to exclude any users that have either a null description or a default Guid value, or only ones where both values are null / default?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend re-thinking your model. Presumably there's code on the other end of this process that has to split the given strings out and line up the IDs with the Descriptions in some way. You're just going to complicate things here and there by encoding these related values in a list of comma-separated strings in the first place. Plus this would be error-prone: what if a Description included a comma? What if a User has a null description, but a non-null ID?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior taking this into consideration. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to skip nulls, so don't add them at all:

```
var ids = string.Join(",", users
    .Where(user => user != null)
    .Select(user=> user.Id));
var descriptions = string.Join(",", users
    .Where(user => user?.Description != null)
    .Select(user=> user.Description));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a check within the lambda expression, as it is a typical function body (just using shorthand).

```
 var descriptions = string.Join(",", users.Select(user => user?.Description ?? string.Empty));
```

If you want to be more expressive:

```
 var descriptions = string.Join(",", users.Select(user => string.IsNullOrEmpty(user?.Description) ? string.Empty : user.Description));
```

Comment: The OP clarified that they're concerned with the properties, not the User objects themselves. And `string.Join` will render null values as empty strings. So this solution just adds code to yield the same result.